# Unable to install any package can't find archive

Tags: package-management, software-installation, archive

```
Linux ubuntu20 5.4.0-47-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 4 19:50:52 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
If I run synaptic I get
E: The package openprinting-gutenprint needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
E: Internal error opening cache (1). Please report.
and synaptic exits.

LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:printing-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch
```

Been having problems with printer filter for epson c60 ..printer filter not loaded. However the printer works for my use. Fixed the problem by editing the file /var/lib/dpkg/status and removing the openprinting-gutenprint entry.

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  No such release, closest is Ubuntu Core 20, however you don't use `synaptic` on a *yy* release such as Ubuntu Core 20, as *yy* releases use only *snaps*.  Please confirm your release.

Comment: Please post the output of lsb_release -a